# Spatial Mapping with Coordinates from a CSV file

Tags: python, geospatial

I'm trying to plot trajectory data on a map using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("/home/hk385/Research_Practice_2023/test_movement.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["longitude", "latitude"])

BBox = ((df.longitude.min(),   df.longitude.max(),      
         df.latitude.min(), df.latitude.max())
> (-74.5514, -74.5040, 40.9036, 40.9228))

ruh_m = plt.imread("/home/hk385/Research_Practice_2023/map.png")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,7))
ax.scatter(df.longitude, df.latitude, zorder=1, alpha= 0.2, c='b', s=10)
ax.set_title('Plotting Spatial Data on I-80')
ax.set_ylim(BBox[0],BBox[1])
ax.set_xlim(BBox[2],BBox[3])
ax.imshow(ruh_m, zorder=0, extent = BBox, aspect= 'equal')
```

I was following the steps from (Source: [https://towardsdatascience.com/easy-steps-to-plot-geographic-data-on-a-map-python-11217859a2db]).

The CSV file I'm using has 157736 rows and a sample of it is:

> capturedTimestamp,journeyId,longitude,latitude,speed,heading,Event_ID,Facility
> 2021-06-07T15:26:12.000-0400,e737e56ea0fe9e25b4ff19c0fe99d34dcd6096d9,-74.52207,40.911275,93.31,268.0,ORI1236464570,I-80
> 2021-06-07T14:50:05.000-0500,2d38325da9ea37678aca648cabb96b9bce873f62,-74.507132,40.910522,100.16,288.5,ORI1236464570,I-80
> 2021-06-07T15:38:46.000-0400,d022c96946c806f141a145f4399b4966f2622ba5,-74.503516,40.909336,0.0,39.0,ORI1236464570,I-80
> 2021-06-07T15:20:00.000-0400,bbbb7fc3891dbbf17283fbe925196af51d1d51f1,-74.529984,40.911024,108.28,268.0,ORI1236464570,I-80
> 2021-06-07T15:39:11.000-0400,22bd4d264e6174958923a2f374e5407fec6b69b3,-74.510526,40.911175,34.55,281.0,ORI1236464570,I-80
> 2021-06-07T15:52:53.000-0400,593edaf963bc4fa04980349970515fd29b8a8989,-74.517537,40.911195,124.41,88.0,ORI1236464570,I-80

But I'm getting an error saying:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/hk385/Research_Practice_2023/Plotting_spatial_data.py", line
> 17, in 
> ax.set_ylim(BBox[0],BBox[1]) TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Since the error suggested that what I'm trying to index is false so I tried switching around the longitude and latitude (the convention is latitude comes before longitude but my CSV file has longitude first). But the same error message keeps on appearing. My second guess would be that not all coordinates in my CSV file might be within the boundaries set. If that is the case, how would I weed out the coordinates out of the boundary that I set?

Answer (score 0):

your error is here:

```
BBox = ((df.longitude.min(), df.longitude.max(),      
         df.latitude.min(), df.latitude.max())
> (-74.5514, -74.5040, 40.9036, 40.9228))
```

`>` is a boolean operator so BBox will be either `True` or `False`...

I guess you want either

```
BBox = (df.longitude.min(), df.longitude.max(),      
        df.latitude.min(), df.latitude.max())
```

or

```
BBox = (-74.5514, -74.5040, 40.9036, 40.9228)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Following your suggestion helped clear out the error message. However, when I run the code, it just says that "Process finished with exit code 0" and there is no visual plot that appears. How would I go about developing a plot? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: hey, not sure what your problem is without the actual error message...the code looks fine otherwise. might be a data issue or something with your python environment  (to make the plot appear try calling `plt.show()` at the end)